# use regular expression to subscribe Kafka topic in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api

I want to use a regular expression to specify Kafka topics for consuming in Apache Flink, just something like `SubscribePattern`in Apache Kafka. But it seems there is no method for doing that!

Is there any way to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this feature is not available yet but there is a JIRA issue [FLINK-8190](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-8190).

The Flink community is in the process of finalizing the Flink 1.4.0 release. It might be included in 1.4.0 or be part of 1.5.0.